# Code Syntax Error

Tags: perl, cgi

Cant seem to get this to work, all I keep getting is a a syntax error.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;

my $Catagory = "Test";

if($Catagory eq 'Home'){
print "Location: http://www.DomainName/\n\n";

}else{

require ("Data/Library/$Catagory.lib");
$Catagory();

}
```

Comment: And what is the syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In second last line you are trying to execute `$Category()` but it only contains a scalar.
Unless something really magic is going on in the file you requires right above.

Answer (score 2):

I'm only guessing at what's in "$Catagory.lib", but it looks like you're trying to reinvent perl modules, calling something from that file. It might be a good idea to read the [perlmod perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html), and create a "Test.pm" module. Subroutines in that module would be used like `Test::foo()`.